# How can I display images and writeups together without hard coding them as seperate pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have a collection of gallery pages that use the same css. Each of the 20 html files is one that i manually opened, changed the img src and adjusted the links to directly point to the previous and next images in my line-up of 20.

I like having unique write-ups and descriptions on each page, but I'm thinking that this is going to be quite a pain to maintain.

Wondering if there is an alternative solution? I was thinking that it would be great to just maintain a speadsheet of the name of the image, the url, and the description. But that also seems a bit more advanced.

Comment: A database, image gallery script, or simple CMS might suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a move from static web pages to something more dynamic. You are correct that it's MUCH more flexible and maintainable, but yes, it's also more advanced than basic HTML. At minimum, you will have to learn a server-side scripting language like [PHP](http://www.php.net/) and a database language like [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) and/or a CMS (Content Management System) like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

A good exercise to get started would be to recreate your site as a Wordpress blog. It's a little bit of an abstraction -- instead of separate pages with your images and text, you have a single page of code that pulls in one image/text set at a time -- but it's a really powerful concept, and will open up so many possibilities with your site.